# How to update variable react native?

Tags: react-native

I have an app, where i need to get known ratio of picture for resizing it later. User can take pictures horizontal and vertical. And of course, ratio changes. So i need to get two different ratios.

There is problem with updating `let horizontalImageRatio = 0;`

How can i solve this, any tips?

my code:

```
Image.getSize(data.uri, (width, height) => { // Pickuping size of the picture
            
            let imageWidth = width;
            let imageHeight = height;

            let stringImageWidth = '' + imageWidth; // Make double to string for storing to asyncstorage
            let stringImageHeight = '' + imageHeight;


            let horizontalImageRatio = 0; // this value should be updated
            let verticalImageRatio = 0;


            // For updating let horizontalImageRatio, but not working outside of this <-- PROBLEM

            const horizontalRatioCalc = () => {
                horizontalImageRatio = imageWidth/imageHeight;
                console.log('horizontal_update', horizontalImageRatio);
            };
            
            const verticalRatioCalc = () => {
                verticalImageRatio = imageWidth/imageHeight;
                console.log('vertical_update', verticalImageRatio);
            };
            

            let stringHorizontalImageRatio = '' + horizontalImageRatio;
            let stringVerticalImageRatio = '' + verticalImageRatio;

            console.log(`Size of the picture ${imageWidth}x${imageHeight}`); // Tells size of the image for the console


            horizontalRatio = async () => {
                if (imageHeight>imageWidth) {

                    verticalRatioCalc();

                    try {
                        AsyncStorage.setItem("imageVerticalRatio", stringVerticalImageRatio),
                        AsyncStorage.setItem("asyncimageWidth", stringImageWidth)
                        AsyncStorage.setItem("asyncimageHeight", stringImageHeight)
                        
                        console.log(`Vertical ratio saved! It's ${stringVerticalImageRatio}`)
                        console.log(`Image Width saved! It's ${stringImageWidth}`)
                        console.log(`Image height saved! It's ${stringImageHeight}`)
    
                    }   catch (e) {
                        console.log(`AsyncStorage saving of image vertical ratio cannot be done.`)
                    }
                }else {
                    
                    horizontalRatioCalc();

                    try {
                        AsyncStorage.setItem("imageHorizontalRatio", stringHorizontalImageRatio),
                        AsyncStorage.setItem("asyncimageWidth", stringImageWidth)
                        AsyncStorage.setItem("asyncimageHeight", stringImageHeight)

                        console.log(`Horizontal ratio saved! It's ${stringHorizontalImageRatio}`)
                        console.log(`Image Width saved! It's ${stringImageWidth}`)
                        console.log(`Image height saved! It's ${stringImageHeight}`)
    
                    }   catch (e) {
                        console.log(`AsyncStorage saving of image vertical ratio cannot be done.`)
                    }
                }
            }
            horizontalRatio();
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Looking at your code, you are defining a variable and initializing it with value 0. We need to know what error you get, but you can try to name it differently, just to see if the problem is in the name of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, apparently, you don't have access to horizontalImageRatio inside of horizontalRatioCalc, the method horizontalRatioCalc has a different scope.
What you can do is change horizontalRatioCalc to receive a parameter and return a value, just like I've done in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xiysai
This is good because now you have a function that can be tested independently.

Or you can also do it this way:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-variable-scope
This way you have access to both the variable and the method.

Comment: Your example opened my eyes. Now I understand completely how that works. Thanks!